# Same as "file" command in MS Windows

Tags: windows

In GNU/Linux System there exists a command, named `file`, which determines the file type.

Is there any similar command/tool in Windows?

In particular, I want to check if a `.lib` file is compiled to 32 or 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function like out-of-the-box. Still, You can use Cygwin to use it's unix version.

There is also free http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html tool.